# Add multiple dictionaries together in a list depend on their same attribute

Tags: python

```
list = [
    {'m': 9, 'y': 2021, 'total': 393.0},
    {'m': 8, 'y': 2021, 'total': 522.0},
    {'m': 7, 'y': 2021, 'total': 207.0},
    {'m': 6, 'y': 2021, 'total': 360.0},
    {'m': 6, 'y': 2021, 'total': 333.0},
    {'m': 6, 'y': 2021, 'total': 100.0},
    {'m': 5, 'y': 2021, 'total': 312.0},
    {'m': 4, 'y': 2021, 'total': 330.0},
    {'m': 3, 'y': 2021, 'total': 462.0},
    {'m': 2, 'y': 2021, 'total': 594.0},
    {'m': 1, 'y': 2021, 'total': 246.0}]
```

As shown above, three dictionaries with same attributes **'m': 6, 'y': 2021** in the list, I'd like to sum the **'total'** but remain **'m': 6, 'y': 2021**, like this:

```
new_list = [
    {'m': 9, 'y': 2021, 'total': 393.0},
    {'m': 8, 'y': 2021, 'total': 522.0},
    {'m': 7, 'y': 2021, 'total': 207.0},
    {'m': 6, 'y': 2021, 'total': 793.0},
    {'m': 5, 'y': 2021, 'total': 312.0},
    {'m': 4, 'y': 2021, 'total': 330.0},
    {'m': 3, 'y': 2021, 'total': 462.0},
    {'m': 2, 'y': 2021, 'total': 594.0},
    {'m': 1, 'y': 2021, 'total': 246.0}]
```

Any Pythonic way to accomplish this?

Comment: `SELECT m, y, SUM(total) FROM list GROUP BY m, y` :)

Comment: Are the dictionaries always contiguous?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes, it always contiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find a total (I'll use int, but maybe you want floating point...), so want a lookup to keep the running totals in. A defaultdict using an int will work.

Calling your `list` `data` instead (to avoid hiding a keyword):

```
from collections import defaultdict
totals = defaultdict(int)
for d in data:
  totals[ (d['m'], d['y']) ] += d['total']
```

This gives the month and year as the key against the totals you want:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {(9, 2021): 393.0, (8, 2021): 522.0, (7, 2021): 207.0, (6, 2021): 793.0, (5, 2021): 312.0, (4, 2021): 330.0, (3, 2021): 462.0, (2, 2021): 594.0, (1, 2021): 246.0})
```

To get this back into  a list:

```
reformatted_data = []
for (m,y),t in totals.items():
  reformatted_data.append( {'m': m, 'y':y', 'total':t} )
```